# Axhspan ignores axis limits (datetime x axis)

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some time series of measurements and I would like to highlight the area below a certain threshold to see where the measured values got below the threshold.
I thought using axhline to mark the threshold and axhspan to highlight the area below would be an obvious choice, but it does not keep to my data limits (say my data is from mid 2019, but the axhspan shows from pre-2000!). [image: Bad axhspan]

When I only plot the axhline [image: good figure without shaded area], it is fine, so it was the axhspan that broke it for some reason.
I also tried "fill_between" and that, too, goes beyond the data limits, although not as badly (in this case, only a few months and only for the axhline).[image: bad fill_between]
Below is my code with the two problematic options commented out at the moment.
What am I doing wrong?
(I would prefer not to bruteforce the axis limits but just keep to the default based on data limits. But if necessary, how can I modify this code to be able to define the x limits that are in datetime format?)

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sourcedata = pd.read_csv(path+sourcefile, encoding= 'unicode_escape')
sourcedata['When']= pd.to_datetime(sourcedata['When'], format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

plt.figure(figsize=(12.3,3.5))
ax=plt.subplot(111)
plt.ylim(-5,35)
plt.ylabel("Air temperature (deg C)", fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel("Date", fontsize=12)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
#plt.axhspan(-5,3, facecolor='powderblue', alpha=0.75)
plt.plot(sourcedata['When'], sourcedata['T1'], lw=0.25, color='orange', label="Sensor 1")
plt.plot(sourcedata['When'], sourcedata['T2'], lw=0.25, color='indigo', label="Sensor 2")
plt.axhline(3.0, color='grey', lw=0.5)
plt.axhline(0.0, color='k', lw=0.25)
#plt.fill_between(ax.get_xlim(), -5, 3, facecolor='powderblue', alpha=0.75)
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: Please, first plot the data and call axhspan later. It will span the full axes (not the full dataspan)

Comment: Oh, right! i moved it up because I was worried it would overprint my data, but it actually doesn't and now I see why it happened - the data weren't loaded in the plot, so obviously the span was unknown at that point! Thanks! You can post it as an answer which I can accept.